# CSS animation doesn't working on IE11 when using transform and position left together

Tags: css, transform, css-animations, css-transforms

The `@keyframes marquee2 {}` does not working on Internet Explorer 11 and also not perfectly working on Edge too. All the other major browsers like Firefox or Chrome are working very well. Still don't know what the reason behind breaking the animation. Why the animation not working when using `left` with`transform: translate(0, 0)` ?

Demo : https://codepen.io/athimannil/full/bojLQN

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 90vw;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.marquee-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-animation: marquee2 20s linear infinite;
  animation: marquee2 20s linear infinite;
}

.marquee-wrap .marquee-img {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.marquee-wrap .marquee-img img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes marquee2 {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="marquee-wrap">
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 01" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 02" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 03" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 04" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 05" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 06" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 07" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 08" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 09" alt=""></div>
    <div class="marquee-img"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=Logo 10" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, or rather fortunately, I don't have IE 11 or Edge to test on, but these bullet points from caniuse.com could be causing your issues

- IE10 and IE11 on Windows 7 have a bug where translate transform values are always interpreted as pixels when used in animations test case
- IE10 and IE11 do not support CSS keyframe blocks inside media queries. Must be defined outside of media query definitions. example

Source: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: The `@keyframes` not inside `media query` and also the animation works very well. The animation not working well only when there is `left` value inside `@keyframe` :-(

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil it would help of you would explain better what is actually happening rather than just saying that it's breaking

Comment: It work very well with `@keyframes marquee2{0%{transform:translate(0, 0)}50%{transform:translate(-100%, 0)}100%{transform:translate(0, 0)}}` unfortunately not working on IE11 when there `left` like `@keyframes marquee2{0%{left:0;transform:translate(0, 0)}50%{left:100%;transform:translate(-100%, 0)}100%{left:0;transform:translate(0, 0)}}`

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil have you tried including `position: absolute;` in the keyframes?

Comment: Still the result is same, however `.marquee-wrap {` has `position: absolute;`